# Swift - Is setting variable property concurrency or multithreading safe?

Tags: ios, swift

As I know setting a variable property when using concurrency or multithreading is not safe but I can't produce a crash with below code.

```
class Node {
    var data = 0
}

var node = Node()
let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue", attributes: .concurrent)

for i in 0...1000 {
    concurrentQueue.async {
        node.data = i    // Should get crash at this line
    }
}
```

### UPDATE1

Thanks @MartinR for pointing out in his comment.

> Enable the “Thread Sanitizer” and it'll report an error immediately.

### UPDATE2

The code got `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS` crash if changing `data` to reference type. It doesn't always happen but sometimes it will. For example:

```
class Data {}

class Node {
    var data = Data()    // Use reference type instead of value type
}

var node = Node()
let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue", attributes: .concurrent)

for i in 0...1000 {
    concurrentQueue.async {
        node.data = Data()    // EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS
    }
}
```

This behavior also happens in Objective-C. Setting object property concurrently will cause crash. But with primitive type, the crash will not happen.

### Questions

- Does setting value type property concurrently will produce a crash?
- If it doesn't produce a crash, what is the difference between setting value type property and setting reference type property?

It's perfect if anyone can also explain why setting reference type property concurrently will produce a crash.

Comment: And why according to you should it crash?

Comment: @PGDev In Swift, by default properties are nonatomic. Your app will get crash when having more than 1 writer on a nonatomic property at a same time. That's what I know. Maybe you can help me explain why it shouldn't crash.

Comment: Non-atomic doesn't mean that app will crash if multiple threads are using the shared resource. It simply means that the final value will not be consistent. You won't know which thread will update the value last.

Comment: Enable the “Thread Sanitizer” and it'll report an error immediately.

Comment: @MartinR Got it. Thanks a lot!!! It's perfect if you can add an answer with some explanation.

Comment: @trungduc Data is not reference type, I had seen a WWDC video and remember the developer explaining its a value type backed by reference storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First off

Class value are stored in heap memory while struct/enum value are stored in stack memory and compiler will try to allocate those memory at compile time (according to my first ref and many online answer). You can check using this code:

```swift
class MemTest {}
class Node {
    var data = MemTest()
}
let node = Node()
let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue", attributes: .concurrent)

for index in 0...100000 {
concurrentQueue.async {
    node.data = MemTest()
    withUnsafePointer(to: &node.data) {
        print("Node data @ \($0)")
    }
    withUnsafePointer(to: node.data) {
        print("Node data value no. \(index) @ \($0)")
    }
}
```

How to: run 2 time and check memory address for value changed time 500, switch MemTest between class and struct will show the difference. Struct will show the same while class will show different address between each time.
So changing value type is just like changing address but the the memory blocks will not be restored while changing reference type is not just changing address but also restore and allocate new memory blocks which will cause the program to break.

### Secondly

But if running first code block of @trungduc with withUnsafePointer, it will show us that the index var of for loop is allocated on the go and in the heap memory, so why is that?
As mentioned before, compiler will only try to allocate the mem if the value type is calculable at compile time. If the they are not calculable, the value will be allocated in heap memory and stay there till the end of scope (according to my second ref). So may be the explanation here is the system will restored the allocated stack after everything is done - end of scope (This I'm not very sure). So in this case the code will not produce a crash as we know. 
My conclusion, the reference type variable's mem will be allocated and restored with no restriction in this case whereas value type variable's mem will be allocated and removed only after the system enter and exit a the scope which contains said variable

### Thanks

- @Gokhan Topcu for [Check section "Memory Management"](https://medium.com/commencis/stop-using-structs-e1be9a86376f)
- @Bruno Rocha for [Check section "Heap Allocated Value Types"](https://swiftrocks.com/memory-management-and-performance-of-value-types.html)

### Some words

My answer is not very solid and might have lots of grammar and spelling error. All update are appreciated. Thanks in advance

### Update

For the part I'm not very sure:
variable `index` was copied to a new memory address with operator `=` so it doesn't matter where the scope end, stack will be released after for loop
After some digging, in @trungduc's code, with reference type variable, it will do 3 things:

1. Allocate new memory for class `Data`
2. Reduce reference to old `Data` stored in `node.data`, even free old `Data` if it's no longer referenced
3. Point `node.data` to new `Data`

While for value type it will do 1 thing only:

1. Point `node.data` to `Integer` in stack memory
   The major difference is in step 2 where there is a chance the old `Data` memory is restored
   There are possibilities where this scenario will happen with reference type

```
________Task 1________|________Task 2________
Allocate new Data #1  |
                      |Allocate new Data #2
Load pointer to old   |
Data                  |
Reduce reference count|
to old Data           |
                      |Load pointer to old
                      |Data
Free old Data         |
                      |Reduce reference count
                      |to old Data (!)
                      |Free old Data (!)
Reference new Data #1 |
                      |Reference new Data #2
```

while with value type, this will happen

```
________Task 1________|________Task 2________
Reference to Integer 1|
                      |Reference to Integer 2
```

In the first case we will have various alternative scenarios but in most case, we get a segmentation fault because thread 2 tries to dereference that pointer after thread 1 free it. There might be other issues like memory leaking as we notice, thread 2 might not reduce reference count to Data #1 correctly
Whereas in second case, it's just changing the pointer.

### Note

In second case, it will never cause crash on Intel CPU but not guaranteed on other CPUs as well because many CPUs do not promise that doing this will not cause a crash.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm quite confused about *allocate those memory at compile time*. Btw, 2 attached posts are really great.

Comment: Sorry, the memory was not allocated at compile time but its size was calculated at compile time and allocated later when running the code and get deallocated when the scope end.

Answer (score -1):

Non-atomic doesn't mean that app will crash if multiple threads are using the shared resource.

**Atomic Properties**

Defining a property as atomic will guarantee that a valid value will be returned. Notice that valid does not always mean correct.

This also does not mean that atomic properties are thread safe. Different threads can attempt to write and read a the same time. One of two values will be returned — the value before the change or the value of the change

**Non-Atomic Properties**

Non atomic properties has no guarantee regarding the returned value. It can be the correct value, a partially written value or even some garbage value.

It simply means that the final value will not be consistent. You won't know which thread will update the value last.

You can refer the [link](https://medium.com/@YogevSitton/atomic-vs-non-atomic-properties-crash-course-d11c23f4366c) for more clarification on this.

Comment: `even some garbage value`. What will happen when you access a garbage value?

Comment: Garbage value doesn't mean nil. So, in any case it won't crash.

Comment: Do you know a crash called `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS`?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS usually means an access to a deallocated instance. in your code node.data will never be nil and at worst will contain garbage value if read while its being written (garbage = some number you do not expect but still will be a valid Int)